# Recess can light conversion to hanging light

Tags: wiring

I have a standard recessed can in my entryway ceiling. I bought a can conversion kit so I could hang a chandelier I brought back from Morocco. When I took the light kit out of the can, there is a black and yellow wire. I connected them to the chandelier (which is just a split transparent wire to a bulb) but it doesn’t seem to work. The switch is just a standard on-off switch (no dimmer). I want to make sure I’m connecting the wires correctly. Is just the black hot? Do I connect both chandelier wires to it and just cap the yellow? Thanks for any help!

Comment: What country are you in? (That affects wiring schemes and in particular the color coding.)

Comment: I’m in the U.S., sorry

Comment: What type of bulb was used in the old can? Was it a standard type or something weird? If something weird, it's highly likely to be low-voltage with a transformer mounted above or to the side of the can.